# Should I use Technopole or Technopolis? (or neither?)

Tags: single-word-requests

I only find Technopolis in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/technopolis) and not on Cambridge dictionary. I do not find Technopole in either, but I can see it is used on some books (
based on [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=technopolis%2C%20technopole&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctechnopolis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctechnopole%3B%2Cc0))

I want to describe:
A city or society characterized by (advanced) technology; (also) a center or area devoted to technological research, development, or production.

For example:
Nearly everywhere, incubators are a very important element of a **technopole's** offer.

Comment: I couldn't find Technopole in Lexico but it is in [Collins on line](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/technopole). [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technopole) says that it was coined in 1990 by Allen J Scott but the Collins entry shows a  usage graph starting with a bit of a bang in 1986 then declining rapidly so either Collins or Wikipedia have got it wrong. Whichever you take it seems to be a late 20th century  invention and not well established. That doesn't surprise me, I'd never heard of it.

Answer (score 2):

One answer is that if you're making up a word, you can make it anything you like ;-)

But actually: English speakers generally will recognise *-polis* as a kind of city. They won't recognise *-pole*. The only common name ending in *-pole* I can think of is *Metropole*, which is usually a hotel name, and I don't think people particularly associate it with Metropolis.

Comment: I like the sound of '*Technocity*' which I thought I'd just made up but has been used https://glosbe.com/en/en/technocity but also has usage as relating to techno songs https://www.azdictionary.com/urban-dictionary/definition/technocity